# UIText field stop allowing input when text reaches end of field

Tags: ios8, uitextfield

Im writing an iOS Storyboard application. I want to alter my UITextField so it stops accepting keyboard input when the text physically reaches the end of the textField (Similar to Snapchat). How do I do this?

Thanks,
JA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `UITextField` class has no max length property, it's relatively simple to get this functionality by setting the text field's delegate and implementing the following delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 25) ? NO : YES;// 25 is custom value. you can use your own.
}
```